# Why Uncache table in spark-sql not working?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm learning Spark SQL, when I'm using spark-sql to uncache a table which has previously cached, but after submitted the uncache command, I can still query the cache table. Why this happened?

**Spark version 3.2.0(Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7)**

**Hadoop version 2.7.7**

**Hive metastore 2.3.9**

**Linux Info**

```
Static hostname: master
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: 15c**********************10b2e19
       Boot ID: 48b**********************efc169b
Virtualization: vmware
```

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-163-generic
Architecture: x86-64

```
spark-sql (default)> CACHE TABLE testCache SELECT * FROM students WHERE AGE = 13;
Error in query: Temporary view 'testCache' already exists
spark-sql (default)> UNCACHE TABLE testCache;
Response code
Time taken: 0.092 seconds
spark-sql (default)> SELECT * FROM testCache;
NAME    rollno  AGE
Kent    8   21
Marry   1   10
Eddie Davis 5   13
Amy Smith   3   13
Barron  3   12
Fleur Laurent   4   9
Ivy 3   8
Time taken: 0.492 seconds, Fetched 7 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNCACHE TABLE` removes the entries and associated data from the in-memory and/or on-disk cache for a given table or view, **not drop** the table. So you can still query it.

Comment: As for my understanding, in my case, after uncache, the underlying table **students** can still be queried(using `SELECT * FROM students`), the uncached table **testCache** should not be able to queried again. But **testCache** still can be query,  Am I wrong?

Comment: You can try to execute ```drop table testCache;```, and then query ```testCache``` again.

Comment: Yes, **drop table** worked，so I get the mechenism now, the cache command `CACHE TABLE testCache SELECT * FROM students;` not only cache the entries in-memory/on-disk, but also created a temporary view. Thanks @过过招 .